# Nginx 404 while it should just proxy pass to php-fpm

Tags: nginx

I have a simple nginx config that used to pass all requests to `/site/index.php`. After upgrading to ubuntu 12.04 this config doesn't work anymore.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name site.com;
    root /site/;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.log;

    location / {
             fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index   index.php;
             fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /site/index.php;
             include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The rule `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /site/index.php;` used to send everything matching 'location /' to index.php but now instead I get a 404 error.

This works

- site/index.php

This doesn't

- site
- site/folder

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does the nginx error log contain any errors? (It should be available under Ubuntu by doing `sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an index specified in your config, try the next config instead:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name site.com;
    root /site/;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.log;

    location / {
             index index.php index.html;
     }

    location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index   index.php;
             fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /site/index.php;
             include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```